# Linq group of chains

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

This is my collection

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee" }
                  .Select(x => new Pair { PropName = x, TypeName = x + "Prop1" })
                  .ToList();
var list2 = new List<string> { "aa", "bb2", "cc", "dd", "ee" }
                  .Select(x => new Pair { PropName = x, TypeName = x + "Prop2" })
                  .ToList();
var list3 = new List<string> { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd" }
                  .Select(x => new Pair { PropName = x, TypeName = x + "Prop3" })
                  .ToList();
var list4 = new List<string> { "aa" }
                  .Select(x => new Pair { PropName = x, TypeName = x + "Prop4" })
                  .ToList();
var list5 = new List<string> { "aa", "bb", "bb5", "cc5" }
                  .Select(x => new Pair { PropName = x, TypeName = x + "Prop5" })
                  .ToList();
var collection = new List<List<Pair>> { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 };
```

It represents some hierarcys (i.e. "aa" is father for "bb")
I want to make something like tree with "Pair" objects. It should have structure like on picture. But with Pair objects. And I do not have any Idea how to do that.

[image]

Comment: The picture represents a graph, not a tree.  Trees don't have cycles.

Comment: So what is your question?  What are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was stupid picture. I changed it. At the end I would lice to get this hierarchy but with Pair objects in the circles. And I have no idea how to do that. Grouping, join? Any suggestion, links, please.

Comment: The structure you describe is very clearly not a `List`, in fact, it's not an `IEnumerable` of any sort (unless you want to be especially clever and say that a graph is enumerable by DFS/BFS/etc). I'd start from scratch and just build a graph structure from the ground up.

Comment: Your Pair object do not contain any references to other Pair object(s). How you are going to build hierarchy?

Comment: Yes this is a way. But now I'm trying to use grouping by whole path (fro instance aa-bb-cc--dd|aa--bb2 ...)